# angular click() event not working after rendering dynamic html

Tags: javascript, angular

Few html elements loaded from server side and angular click() event also part of it. but event is not firing after rendering the elements. I understand that i need to notify the DOM. I can not do this.

**component.ts**

```
mport { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: '../Views/Dashboard.html',
    providers: []
})

export class DashboardComponent {
    public deviceData="<div (click)="Go()">Click</div>"; //e.x: loaded from server
    constructor(){

    }
    Go():void{
       alert("Go");
    }

}
```

**html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="deviceData"></div>
```

Comment: Where did you read that it should work?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com could not write such a thing

Comment: ok, do you have any solution for it, i need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+innerHTML+click+binding

Answer (score 3):

You can bind event using

```
<div class="classname" [innerHTML]="deviceData"></div>

this.deviceData = "<a herf='javascript:void(0);'>Click</a>";

ngOnInit()
{
 var obj=this;
    $(document).on('click', '.classname', function () {
        obj.Go();
    });
}

Go() 
{
    alert("Go");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Manish, but jquery with angular bit overwhelming work. Thanks, let me try with your given code snippets.

Comment: thanx ..for using jquery you have to write "declare var $: any;" this line to typing.d.ts

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

A click function (or any Angular specific tag) to be rendered as html is not best practice. Try to only render bare basic html and put the click function in separately.